# how to get aiff file bit rate c#

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio, bitrate, aiff

Here, my task is to fetch aiff audio details including bit rate. But with this code I am able to fetch sample rate, bits per sample and channel only. Is there any way to get bit rate too?

```
public void GetAudioDetails()
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream("..\\guitar.aiff",FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   fs.CopyTo(ms);
   ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   var ddf = new AiffFileReader(ms);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bitrate is average bytes per second * 8. So use the following code:

```
var bitRate = ddf.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 8;
```

Comment: Hi @Mark, here for my file average bytes per second is 192000. As per your answer it would come around, 1536000 (192000*8). Is it right ??

Comment: but when I used 128 bit rate mp3 file in Mp3FileReader() function, the average bytes per second was given as 176400. Now as per your calculation its bit rate become, 1411200. which is completely different from the source bit rate. I have checked the file bit rate using AudioInspection demo, which is 128 bit only.

Comment: because Mp3FileReader converts to uncompressed PCM for you. Look at Mp3WaveFormat instead

Comment: Will this technique applies for MFTReader too??

Comment: It seems with MFTReader it is difficult to find the source bit rate of a mp3 fie.